# Mega menu button color is not change in sub menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have set CSS for each button on main menu.It's change to special color when mouse hover or pressed on button.But it's not change in sub menu.I can't find what I missing.

Home / Category it's ok.

Home / Category / Sub Category | It's must be green but is not !

When I look to source code for sub page.It's show this code.

```
<li id="menu-item-7" class="ucuncu-nav menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor menu-item-7 mega-menu mega-recent-featured ">
```

It's fix when I add this line's on html.

```
current-menu-parent current-post-parent
```

So,it's fixing when I put like that.

```
<li id="menu-item-7" class="ucuncu-nav menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-7 mega-menu mega-recent-featured ">
```

But what I miss on CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly,I fix it just write some code in ucuncu class.

```
.ucuncu-nav.mega-menu,
.ucuncu-nav.menu-item-type-taxonomy{
    background-color:aquamarine;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `current` attribute you are adding is setting some styling which will change the color since `current` is usually used on the tab you are currently on or hovering over.

```
    .ucuncu-nav:hover,
    .ucuncu-nav.current-menu-item, 
    .ucuncu-nav.current-page-parent,
    .ucuncu-nav.current_page-parent,
    .ucuncu-nav.current-menu-parent,
    .ucuncu-nav.current-page-ancestor{  
     background-color: #669900 !important;

}
```

Is the code you are looking for.

Comment: I coded this class.I know that.How can I fix this ?

Comment: You said it yourself. `current-menu-parent current-post-parent ` when you added this it fixed, so add it to the submenu class HTML.